# A chamada __fastcall, necessário ou não?

Tags: c++, funções

Qual a utilidade de usar **__fastcall** na chamada de funções em C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na maioria das vezes a convenção de chamada não é considerável. Quando usa a convenção *fastcall*, os primeiros argumentos são passados através de registradores padrões da chamada.

Em funções sucintas demais ou que são chamadas em um único ponto do programa inteiro, o melhor é implementar *inline* com suas consequentes otimizações, o que sequer resulta em chamadas em tempo de execução. Já em outros casos, depende de muitos fatores, como a localização dos dados antes, durante e depois da chamada. Há por exemplo, instruções de máquina que requerem os dados de entrada em registradores específicos (como `mul`, `imul`, `div` e `idiv`) e é bom que a convenção de chamada utilizada favoreça isso.

Se precisa de performance extrema e puder mensurar com suficiente precisão, o que é difícil, pode experimentá-la para ver se compensa. O ganho pode ser irrisório e muitas vezes é necessário fazer adaptações que prejudicam o código. Em algumas arquiteturas, sequer se tenta usá-la, inclusive é comum em arquiteturas modernas ela ser mais lenta que outras convenções de chamadas, tornando o uso raro.